# delete links border in Firefox and IE when open that links in a new window

Tags: css

When you open a link in new window in Firefox and IE, and visit the new window, and come back to first window , that link have a dotted border.
I don't want this border in my site.
How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stupid people like me, the graphic issue can be found on other html elements on firefox, the solution is to use **::-moz-focus-inner** on them, for example:

```
a::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

u can use this CSS for resolve this issue :

```
a :: -moz-focus-inner{border:0;}
a:focus, a:active{
outline:none;
ie-dummy:expression(this.hideFocus = true);
border: 0px none;
}
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, can i have some clarification about the "a ::" notation?

Answer (score 1):

#### Just use this CSS:

```
a:active, a:focus {outline: 0;}
```

This is the [`outline`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) CSS rule.

*On a small note, this will give an issue with accessibility.*

#### You can check with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sWpSq/